# Data type for holding different values C++

Tags: c++

I'm wondering how to load a number of images in a function and assign it to one variable so i can call on them and also hold information for those images.

For example :

```
src = tile1.png
x = 10
y = 11
```

What kind of data type would i need ?

My goal is to loop through lines in a text file, load each image with its relevant information so the images are pre-loaded and ready to be displayed on the screen. I just a little stuck on how it would be done.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question... but wouldn't you just create a class that has the information attributes you want?

Comment: How about a... simple... `struct`/`class`? It seems to me that you need [a good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks).

Comment: @Tyler so i would need to generate each one at a time like `ClassName unique_name();` for every image?

Comment: @Xeo books are the worst choice for me i tend to learn better learning from actual scripts and fiddling with them.

Comment: You'd use an array for that, specifically a `std::vector<YourClass>`. But then again, please get a book. No excuses. They're (sadly, if you want) essential to learn *good* C++.

Comment: I heard there are some pretty good tutorials on them there internetz..

Comment: @Aesthete any sites you can suggest would be welcome :) I just bout c++ primer 5th edition too :)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `struct`.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct a_new_datatype{

    string name;
    int age;
    char gender;


};

int main(){

    a_new_datatype my_own_datatype;

    my_own_datatype.name = "Christopher";
    my_own_datatype.age = 34;
    my_own_datatype.gender = 'M';

    cout << "Name: " << my_own_datatype.name << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << my_own_datatype.age << endl;
    cout << "Gender: " << my_own_datatype.gender << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Will have a fiddle with this!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to roll your own system, you could make an abstract base `Image` class. Then create a concrete sub-class for each image type you want to handle (e.g. `ImageJpeg`, `ImagePng`). These concrete sub-classes can then be simple wrappers around an image-loading library like [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) or [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/). Have a factory-function that create a concrete object but returns a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) of the abstract class. These can the be stored in standard container such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

There are however already many existing image libraries, both specific (like libjpeg/libpng mentioned above) and generic (like [SDL_Image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) or [Boost GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html)). Some of them have already C++ classes, some does not so need to be wrapped by you.